# Changing format of TODAY() in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm using today to aquire todays date and then adding a static value to the end of it using the following:

```
=TODAY()&"T23:00:00"
```

Which Returns `43202T23:00:00`

I really need it in the format `2018-04-12T23:00:00`

Any help on this would be great!

Comment: You could format the cells as yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss then =TODAY() + TIME(23,0,0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple ways to accomplish this, depending on whether your goal is a formatted String (to display) or a numeric value (such as data type `Date`) for storing or using with calculations.

---

### If you want a *formatted* date/time result (to display to the user)...

> Use the [`TEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) worksheet function:
>
> ```
> =TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"T23:00:00"
> ```

...the reason this works is because `TODAY()` returns a `Date` data type, which is basically just a number representing the date/time, (where 1 = midnight on `January 1, 1900`, 2 = midnight on `January 2, 1900`, 2.5 = noon on `January 2, 1900`,etc).

You can convert the date type to a String (text) with the `TEXT` function, in whatever format you like. The example above will display today's date as `2018-04-12`.

If, for example, you wanted the date portion of the string displayed as`April 12, 2018` then you would instead use:

```
TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm d, yyyy")
```

Note that the `TEXT` worksheet function (and VBA's `Format` function) **always return Strings**, ready to be concatenated with the rest of the String that you're trying to add (`"T23:00:00"`).

---

### If you want to use the result in *calculations*...

If you instead want the result to be in a **Date** type, then instead of *concatenating* a **string** (produced by the TEXT function) to a **string** (from `"T23:00:00"`), you could instead *add* a **date** to a **date**:

```
=TODAY()+TIME(23,0,0)
```

or

```
=TODAY()+TIMEVALUE("23:00")
```

..and then you can format it as you like to show or hide Y/M/D/H/M/S as necessary with Number Formats (shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>).

---

## More Information:

- MSDN : [**`TEXT` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)
- MSDN : [**`TIMEVALUE` Function** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/timevalue-function)
- MSDN : [**`TIME` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/time-function-9a5aff99-8f7d-4611-845e-747d0b8d5457)

Comment: @KyleMoffett - You're welcome, I'm glad you got it figured out!

Comment: @KyleMoffett please select this as the correct answer by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: @ashleedawg I am going to delete my answer, yours is better.  Just wanted to inform you so you can remove the references and make it a stand alone.